# Snackbar doesn't show action the first time it pops up

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-design-library, android-snackbar

Just as the title says. I implemented the Snackbar feature in my app, the first time the snackbar pops up it doesn't show the action, but on the second time it does. The code is below.

```
    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        if (result.isFailure()) {

            if (result.getResponse() == IabHelper.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
                mIsPremium = true;
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                removebutton.setText("PURCHASED");

                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.container2), "Purchased", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("UNDO", mOnClickListener)
                        .setActionTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFAB40"))
                        .setDuration(4000).show();
            }



        } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            mIsPremium = true;
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            removebutton.setText("PURCHASED");
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.container2), "Ads have been removed", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("UNDO", mOnClickListener)
                    .setActionTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFAB40"))
                    .setDuration(4000)
                    .show();
        }

        mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        };

    }

};
```

Comment: Can you post the code from where you call this?

Comment: Done. I don't think it matters though, because I put it in a separate button's onClick method and the same thing happened.

Answer (score 0):

When you first time call your function your onClickListener is null.

Move:

```
mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    };
```

Before if (result.isFailure()), or even to some kind of onCreate().